# head and grep display text different than gedit

Tags: linux, bash, character-encoding

I try to get some information from log file, but I get numbers using grep and I want get text like I see in gedit.
Result of `file` command:
`ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators`
Also I checked that `nano` displays text.

[image: result of head and gedit]

picture is showing ,1650 numbers in CLI and NMEA text in gedit accordingly, as a result of viewing beginning of the same file.

`od -tx1a your_file | head -n30`

```
0000000  4e  4d  45  41  2c  24  47  4e  47  47  41  2c  31  32  30  38
          N   M   E   A   ,   $   G   N   G   G   A   ,   1   2   0   8
0000020  32  34  2e  37  35  32  2c  35  32  31  36  2e  33  31  34  34
          2   4   .   7   5   2   ,   5   2   1   6   .   3   1   4   4
0000040  2c  4e  2c  30  32  30  35  39  2e  30  38  37  37  2c  45  2c
          ,   N   ,   0   2   0   5   9   .   0   8   7   7   ,   E   ,
0000060  30  2c  30  2c  2c  35  37  2e  35  2c  4d  2c  33  38  2e  39
          0   ,   0   ,   ,   5   7   .   5   ,   M   ,   3   8   .   9
0000100  2c  4d  2c  2c  2a  36  31  0d  2c  31  36  35  39  30  31  30
          ,   M   ,   ,   *   6   1  cr   ,   1   6   5   9   0   1   0
0000120  31  30  34  30  30  30  0a  4e  4d  45  41  2c  24  47  50  47
          1   0   4   0   0   0  nl   N   M   E   A   ,   $   G   P   G
0000140  53  41  2c  41  2c  31  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c
          S   A   ,   A   ,   1   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
0000160  2c  2c  2c  39  39  2e  39  39  2c  39  39  2e  39  39  2c  39
          ,   ,   ,   9   9   .   9   9   ,   9   9   .   9   9   ,   9
0000200  39  2e  39  39  2a  33  30  0d  2c  31  36  35  39  30  31  30
          9   .   9   9   *   3   0  cr   ,   1   6   5   9   0   1   0
0000220  31  30  34  30  30  30  0a  4e  4d  45  41  2c  24  47  4c  47
          1   0   4   0   0   0  nl   N   M   E   A   ,   $   G   L   G
0000240  53  41  2c  41  2c  31  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c
          S   A   ,   A   ,   1   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
0000260  2c  2c  2c  39  39  2e  39  39  2c  39  39  2e  39  39  2c  39
          ,   ,   ,   9   9   .   9   9   ,   9   9   .   9   9   ,   9
0000300  39  2e  39  39  2a  32  43  0d  2c  31  36  35  39  30  31  30
          9   .   9   9   *   2   C  cr   ,   1   6   5   9   0   1   0
0000320  31  30  34  30  30  30  0a  4e  4d  45  41  2c  24  42  44  47
          1   0   4   0   0   0  nl   N   M   E   A   ,   $   B   D   G
0000340  53  41  2c  41  2c  31  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c  2c
          S   A   ,   A   ,   1   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
```

Comment: What does `od -tx1a your_file | head -n30` show? Please ad it to your question as a text, not as a picture.

Comment: thanks for od command I will keep it in mind.

Comment: You are welcome. In the hex dump we can see that some lines are terminated using CR (0d) while others using LF (0a, shown as nl). The output of the gnss logger is really messy! --- `od` is short for octal dump (the default output is octal), `-t` is output format (type), `x1` is for single byte hex numbers, `a` is for ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal displays line breaks for \n (the LF) but your file contains seemingly different line breaks. It's not CRLF, as claimed, because otherwise your terminal would in fact show the line breaks!

Try piping through `dos2unix` for display:

```
dos2unix < somefile.nmea | head
```

However, to be honest, the fact that there's two different kinds of line breaks in your text file makes me very suspicious of whatever GPS firmware produced this. NMEA is by the way pretty clear on this, the separator between lines is LF, so that simple output on your console should definitely show the right thing!

Comment: This was a line endings. In original file there were single 0xA and single 0xD. I don't have dos2unix but I save a copy from gedit and set line endings to "Unix". It replaced all 0xD to 0xA, new file length stay the same. Now grep displays OK. It's file from google gnss logger.

Comment: Whatever Google gnss logger is! It produces data that is not following the unambiguous NEMA standard.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.location.gps.gnsslogger&hl=pl&gl=US I used it first and one time, but it gives you ability to save a log file of raw GPS messages (and much more localization info) at Android phone.

Comment: Aha. You might want to leave a negative review and point the developers at the nmea 108 standard, which is a standard that a whole industry does well (it's idiotically simple to not make that mistake)